# Semicolon syntax in jquery has me baffled

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the fairly simple code:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.showprice').click(function () {
            $(this).parent.children.hide();
        }); 
    })
 </script>
```

Jshints in Fiddle fusses about the first line, saying, missing ; and fusses at the last line with unrecoverable error.

Q1:  What am I missing here.  My suspicion is that it's like perl, and is complaining about a semicolon when there is something entirely different wrong.

Q2:  Pointers or links to better methods for tracking down syntax errors.

---

Based on the first reply below, I made the changes suggested, bring the code up to this:

I edited the code to be:

```
1 < script > 
2     $(document).ready(function () {
3     $('.showprice').click(function () {
4         $(this).parent().children().hide();
5     }); 
6    });
7    < /script>
```

And now I get fusses about missing ; on line 1, 
"expected assignment or function call on line 6
and unrecoverable error on line 7.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-semicolons

Comment: Uh? jsHint only complains about the last line http://www.jshint.com/. Of course you shouldn't include  `< script >` for the test. There is actually no syntax error in your code (but you will have runtime errors).

Comment: A note on code formatting: rather than add spaces to your markup, just use the `{}` tool to mark it as code - it will be escaped for you. You'll notice syntax-highlighting kicks in too.

Comment: I'd say using a debugger is the easiest way to identify syntax errors.

Comment: Don't include the `<script>` tags when using jsHint!

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, you should change:

```
$(this).parent.children.hide();
```

to:

```
$(this).parent().children().hide();
```

`parent()` and `children()` is a method. You need `()` here.

You also need to add `;` after closing `})` of your DOM ready wrapper, final code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.showprice').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().children().hide();
    }); 
}); // <-- Here
```

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford - I hope you're not including the `<script>` tags (which are obviously not valid JavaScript)...

Comment: THAT was the problem.  I started on W3CSchool and the script is there as part of the embedding process in html.

Comment: I'd personally avoid W3C Schools like the plague... and you should be able to check for syntax errors (and runtime errors) by using a basic debugger.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford Seem like you don't understand other people suggestions. You're correct that normally we should wrap our javascript code inside `<script></script>` tag. But in your case, you're using `jsHint` to test your code, those errors that you received at this moment are coming from `jsHint` because they automatically wrap your code inside `<script></script>` already, so you don't need to do it one more time, that's it :)

Comment: 17.5k reputation in 3 month ! You are the boss :D I wish I were as good as you :P

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to put `;` on the last `)` of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.showprice').click(function () {
        $(this).parent.children.hide();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Tried that.  Now JSHint fusses about that line, "surplus semicolon"